# Labview: Changing while loop condition not working

Tags: labview

I have a while loop that is set to terminate upon false but I would like to change to terminate upon true. I'm supposed to be able to right click on the termination condition to change it but it's not giving me the option.[image]

Here is an image of what I get for reference. I'm supposed to see something like this [image]

Anyone know why it's different? I'm on Labview 5.0 if that matters.

Comment: Are you sure you are clicking on the loop icon? Not just outside it? Your cursor is right on the border!

Comment: You are going to have to show us more of the content.  Your clicking on something with *eturn count*.  Are you sure looping is possible where you are clicking?  I don't know the program, but the software will only give options which are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might have changed (LabVIEW 5 was released in 1999) you just need to right-click in later versions (I was wrong earlier - however I've checked on Labview 8.6 and 2014).

Maybe you are not clicking on the exact position.

Also, if you are developing on two (or more monitors), sometimes there are some unexpected side effects (especially if you are using monitors with significantly different resolutions). If you use two monitors, I would recommend:

- unplug the extra monitors and restart Labview
- use a smaller resolution (e.g. don't use 4K resolution on a 27 inch monitor, its going to be a nightmare).